# Displaying Unicode/ASCII Characters on console or window

Tags: c++, unicode, windows-xp, ascii, special-characters

I couldn't display a 'bullet' of character code `DEC 149` which can be found on [ASCII Chart](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

```
cout << char(149) << endl;
```

it comes out as `ò` on console window. I know a few characters from charmap that I'd like to use but how would i know their character codes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output Unicode to Console Using C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849010/output-unicode-to-console-using-c)

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: What platform is this?  This is a console issue, not a C++ issue.

Comment: Tagged accordingly.  However, that does make this a duplicate of the question KennyTM cited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ASCII only defines character codes 0 through 127.  If you want to use codes above that, then you need to specify an ANSI code page.  The chart you referenced is using the Latin-1 code page and your console is apparently using something else.

You need to set your console code page to Latin-1 for your characters to display as desired.  There's no standard C++ way to do this.  If you're programming on Windows, you can use the SetConsoleOutputCP() function.  The code page id for Latin-1 on Windows is 1252.

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have a way to do this; the standard way would be to use `std::wcout`. Unfortunately that appears a bit broken on VC++

Answer (score 0):

To get the Unicode character codes you can look them up in the [Unicode code charts](http://unicode.org/charts/).

[decodeunicode.org](http://www.decodeunicode.org/) is nice for interactive browsing.