# is it possible to obtain unicode characters on Windows XP console using MinGW?

Tags: c++, unicode, console, windows-xp, mingw

I found bunch of code examples but these are for MSVC++, these examples fail under MinGW so I wonder if it is possible at all in MinGW ? Maybe this is feature available only in MSVC ?

If it is possible, can you please provide me with simple self sustainable code that would print a Hello World message but in for example russian (привет мир).

Comment: How is talking about a space station the same as "hello world"? :-)

Comment: [This code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx) appears to work, subject to selecting a suitable font.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849010/output-unicode-to-console-using-c

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a character array and then print it. The only thing you have to be careful is that you have to save it as a UNICODE file and to use a compiler that can read UNICODE files.

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
 {
 using namespace std;
 wchar_t a[]={'п','р','и','в','е','т',' ','м','и','р'};
 for(int x=1; a[x]!='\0'; x++)
      wcout<<a[x];
 return 0;
 }
```

This will print the output as follows.

```
привет мир
```

OR, if you want just ASCII characters, you can print them by specifying it's character code.

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
 {
 for(int x=1; x<40; x++)
      cout<<char(x)<<"\t";
 return 0;
 }
```

This will print the ASCII characters corresponding to the number as shown below.

```
☺        ☻        ♥        ♦        ♣        ♠
        ♫        ☼        ►        ◄        ↕        ‼        ¶        §
▬        ↨        ↑        ↓
```