# How can I make dynamic strings to work with UTF-8 in console?

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, console-application, iostream

Most of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849040/607407) and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/607407) here on SO use to put `L` before any UTF-8 string. I found no explantion of what it is, in the source code, the constant is, according to my IDE, defined in `winnt.h`.

This is how I use it, without knowing what it is:

```
std::wcout<<L"\"Přetečení zásobníku\" is Stack overflow in Czech.";
```

Obviously, constant concatenation cannot be applied on variables:

```
void printUTF8(const char* str) {
  //Does not make the slightest bit of sense
  std::wcout<<L str; 
}
```

So what is it and how to add it to dynamic strings?

Comment: L is a 16 bit designator (mostly, it could be anything in theory) and a UTF-8 string is not 16-bit.

Comment: Oh, well, I might be using UTF-16 in fact...

Comment: There is another issue here which is the Console. I'll update my post but could you tell us what you are getting on the console with your example?

Comment: Currently my code works - that's because I'm using the function that you've suggested already. However I'll reconsider using UTF-8.

Comment: I may have answered a question that wasn't asked then! If you have a UTF-8 string you can convert it to something that wcout wants with the MultiByteToWideChar() function. That would make a normal string into an "L" string.

Answer (score 1):

L is an indication to the C compiler that the string is composed of "wide characters". In Windows, these would be UTF-16 - each character that you put in the string is 16 bits, or two bytes, wide:

```
L"This is a wide string"
```

In contrast, a UTF-8 string is always a string composed of bytes. ASCII characters (A-Z 0-9 etc) are encoded the way they have always been - in the range 0x00 to 0x7F (or 0 to 127). International characters (like ř) are encoded using multiple bytes in the range 0x80 to 0xFF - there is a very good explanation on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The advantage is that it can be represented using ordinary C strings.

```
"This is an ordinary string, but also a UTF-8 string"

"This is a C cedilla in UTF-8: \xc3\x87"
```

However, if you are typing these international characters in to actual code, your editor needs to know that you are typing in UTF-8 so it can encode the characters correctly - like the C cedilla above. Then the string will be passed correctly to your function.

In your case, your comment indicates that you are using UTF-16. In which case there are two other issues:

- The console will, by default, not output Unicode characters correctly. You need to change the font to a truetype font like Lucida Console
- You also need to change the output mode to a Unicode UTF-16 one. You can do this with:

  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"Přetečení zásobníku is Stack overflow in Czech." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why is the `_setmode` required when you're using `wcout`? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I believe (but not sure) that otherwise the console will assume ANSI and convert the UTF-16 to garbage!

Comment: @MarkRansom: the purpose of the wide streams is to convert to/from external byte-oriented encoding. well except that as i see it the design with 8 standard stream objects mapped to 3 OS byte streams, where there's no way to check whether any particular use somewhere is *invalid* (C level "orientation", wide or narrow), sucks. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`L""` is a WIDE string. That is to say, it's a a `wchar_t[1]`. UTF-8 strings can't be wide, since they are multi-byte (variable length). VC++ is slightly wrong and made wide strings variable length, UTF-16 to be precise. But usually they're UTF-32.

The problem with multi-byte strings is that there are many different encodings, and UTF-8 is only one of them. Windows does not in fact natively support UTF-8 encodings. `MessageBoxA()` for instance can use any encoding but UTF-8. There's just one exception to that, which is `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, ...)` which is what you'd need here.

Comment: re "VC++ is slightly wrong and made wide strings variable length", that doesn't make sense to me. What did you mean to write? Are you perhaps referring to C99/C++11 rules, I guess resulting from politics / fanboyism, which came long after Windows and Visual C++?

Comment: Narrow strings can be multi-byte (e.g. `mbclen` can be less than `strlen`). Wide strings can't be, each character should fit in one `wchar_t` and there's only `wcslen`. Windows of course defines `WCHAR`, which historically mapped to `unsigned short`. Mapping `WCHAR` to `wchar_t` is where things get complicated.

Comment: I mostly agree with that, but it's misleading in two ways. First, the notion that conceptual character (displayed as a single graphic) is necessarily representable as a single 32-bit encoding value. That's simply not so in general. I.e., the C++ standard library is botched also with UTF-32: it's just a matter of degree, and for the politics, a matter of what one can make the ignorant masses believe. The second way it's a bit misleading is that it implies that Windows WCHAR was mapped to wchar_t at some point. I can't remember that it's not been so, ever. I.e., C99 is at fault.

Comment: **UPDATE**: I find that the wording I thought was introduced in C99, was there already in C90. So, Microsoft is at fault, not C99 and Unix-land politics, as I maintained. Mea culpa!

Comment: The first version of Windows NT was released in 1993; at that time, [16 bits was all you needed](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) to encode the entire Unicode character set.  The character set was extended in Unicode 2.0, introduced in 1996.  By then I expect it was too late for Microsoft to change their definition of `wchar_t` and the best they could do was change the encoding from UCS-2 to UTF-16 ([as of Windows 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2#Use_in_major_operating_systems_and_environments)).

Answer (score 0):

Re your actual question

> **”** what is [the `L` prefix] and how to add it to dynamic strings?

This is very different from the title of the question at the time I’m writing this, namely “How can I make dynamic strings to work with UTF-8 in console?”

In short, **UTF-8** is an encoding of Unicode where the basic encoding unit is 8 bits, commonly called a byte (more precisely it's an octet), while the `L` prefix forms a **wide** character or string literal, where the encoding unit typically is 16 or 32 bits – in Windows it’s 16 bits, as in original Unicode.

A wide character or string literal is based on the `wchar_t` type instead of `char`.

In Windows a wide string is encoded as **UTF-16**. The most common sixty thousand or so Unicode characters are represented with single `wchar_t` values, but some seldom used Chinese ideograms etc. require two successive `wchar_t` values, called a **surrogate pair**.

The use of 16 bit encoding unit in Windows was established around 1992. I am not sure when UTF-16 was adopted (as an extension of then UCS-2 encoding), it was just a bit later. <del>So this was established long before C99 required that all characters of the wide character set should be representable with single `wchar_t` values. That requirement appears to have been a pure political maneuver, ensuring that no Windows C compiler could be formally conforming, a general ISO programming language standard that applied only to Unix-land. Unfortunately, since C++11 was based on C99 we now have that also in C++11, ensuring that no Windows C++ compiler can be fully conforming. Pure idiocy. If you ask me.</del>

***Errata***, re deleted text above: according to [Wikipedia’s article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) the wording about a single `wchar_t` being sufficient for any character in the “extended character set” was there already in C90. Which makes the incompatibility between Windows and the C and C++ standards the fault of Microsoft, not the fault of the C committee. It still appears to be political and fairly idiotic, but (enlightened) with others to blame than I maintained at first…

---

One way to work with wide dynamic strings is to use `std::wstring`, from the `<string>` header.

With Visual C++ you can use a **`wmain`** function instead of standard `main`, as an easy way to get wide command line arguments.

`wmain` is also supported by MinGW64 (IIRC) g++, although not yet by ordinary MinGW g++, as of g++ 4.8.something. It is however easy to implement in terms of the Windows API. Unless you require strict standard-conforming code that provides the special main function features such as ability to declare it with or without arguments, but hey, let's be practical about things.

---

Example that compiles fine with both Visual C++ 12.0 and g++ 4.8.2:

```
// Source encoding: UTF-8 with BOM.

#include <io.h>         // _setmode
#include <fcntl.h>      // _O_WTEXT

#include <iostream>     // std::wcout, std::endl
#include <string>       // std::wstring
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    _setmode( _fileno( stdin ), _O_WTEXT );
    _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_WTEXT );

    wcout << L"Hi, what’s your name? ";
    wstring username;
    getline( wcin, username );
    wcout << L"Welcome to Windows C++, " << username << "!" << endl;
}
```

Note that with Windows ANSI source this won’t compile with g++ unless you specify the source encoding with the appropriate compiler option.