# How can I read accented characters in C++ and use them with isalnum?

Tags: c++, input, ascii, diacritics, strchr

I am programming in French and, because of that, I need to use accented characters. I can output them by using
`#include <locale>` and `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`, but there seems to be a problem when I read accented characters. Here is simple example I made to show the problem :

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const string SymbolsAllowed = "+-*/%";

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");    // makes accents printable

    // Traduction : Please write a string with accented characters
    // 'é' is shown correctly :
    cout << "Veuillez écrire du texte accentué : ";

    string accentedString;
    getline(cin, accentedString);

    // Accented char are not shown correctly :
    cout << "Accented string written : " << accentedString << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < accentedString.length(); ++i)
    {
        char currentChar = accentedString.at(i);

        // The program crashes while testing if currentChar is alphanumeric.
        // (error image below) :
        if (!isalnum(currentChar) && !strchr(SymbolsAllowed.c_str(), currentChar))
        {
            cout << endl << "Character not allowed : " << currentChar << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "No unauthorized characters were written." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an **output example** before the program crashes :

```
Veuillez écrire du texte accentué : éèàìù
Accented string written : ʾS.?—
```

I noticed the debugger from Visual Studio shows that I have written something different than what it outputs :

```
[0] -126 '‚'    char
[1] -118 'Š'    char
[2] -123 '…'    char
[3] -115 ''     char
[4] -105 '—'    char
```

The error shown seems to tell that **only characters between -1 and 255 can be used** but, according to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) the value of the accented characters I used in the example above **do not exceed this limit**.

Here is a **picture of the error dialog** that pops up : [Error message: Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oejOt.jpg)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or give me a solution for this? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Range for ASCII Table is 0-127 only. For unicode character, you need to use `wchar_t`. By the way, in your system `char` is `signed` type, so the debugger will show the negative value for the values which isn't in range 0-127.
Remark: `char` is neither `signed char` nor `unsigned char`

Comment: use Unicode. Do not use locale. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2849010/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/995714

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `char` is a signed type on your system (indeed, on many systems) so its range of values is -128 to 127. Characters whose codes are between 128 and 255 look like negative numbers if they are stored in a `char`, and that is actually what your debugger is telling you:

   ```
   [0] -126 '‚'    char
   ```

   That's -126, not 126. In other words, 130 or 0x8C.
2. `isalnum` and friends take an `int` as an argument, which (as the error message indicates) is constrained to the values `EOF` (-1 on your system) and the range 0-255. -126 is not in this range. Hence the error. You could cast to `unsigned char`, or (probably better, if it works on Windows), use the two-argument [`std::isalnum` in `<locale>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalnum)
3. For reasons which totally escape me, Windows seems to be providing console input in [CP-437](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195060.aspx) but processing output in [CP-1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx). The high half of those two code pages is completely different. So when you type `é`, it gets sent to your program as 130 (0xC2) from CP-437, but when you send that same character back to the console, it gets printed according to CP-1252 as an (low) open single quote `‚` (which looks a lot like a comma, but isn't). So that's not going to work. You need to get input and output to be on the same code page.
4. I don't know a lot about Windows, but you can probably find some useful information in the [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That page includes links to Windows-specific functions which set the input and output code pages.
5. Intriguingly, the accented characters in the source code of your program appear to be CP-1252, since they print correctly. If you decide to move away from code page 1252 -- for example, by adopting Unicode -- you'll have to fix your source code as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about the CP-437 input, CP-1252 output you mention. What I see by default is CP-437 for both input and output.

Comment: @jerry: could the call to setlocale have changed output but not input cp? The output cp must be 1252 based on observed output...

Comment: I suppose the startup code could be doing something, but I did nothing but retrieve and print out the code pages. Perhaps I should test with a program that doesn't use/link with the standard library at all.

Comment: I just wrote and ran a program that doesn't use or link the standard library at all. All it does is retrieve the CP for the console (both input and output) and display them. It's showing 437 for both (Windows 7, installed as US English user).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: OK, I edited my answer slightly. I'm thinking that the call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` is the culprit, but I'm not 100% confident of that. And OP is presumably a French user, which may involve different defaults.

Comment: @rici I have tried to remove `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`, but it did not really help to solve the problem. The only thing it seems to do is to output a string with accents correclty as one of my teacher told me. The problem really seems to be related to the default CP-437 from the input as you mentionned earlier. And, I live in Canada so the default CP should be CP-1252 as I also learned and see on the [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @PierreCollardSuero: Yes, you will need the setlocale. I don't think that is the problem; rather, it is as you say a problem with the input code page. I don't know why setlocale doesn't change both of them. I'm not a Windows programmer; not even a Windows user, so I have no machine experiment with, but I hope the hints here are enough for you to find a solution. My sense is that Windows does not help resolve locale issues as much as it could. If it were me, I would try to find a Unicode solution because these days that is more general, but it might not fit you particular use case. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With the `is*` and `to*` functions, you really need to cast the input to `unsigned char` before passing it to the function:

```
if (!isalnum((unsigned char)currentChar) && !strchr(SymbolsAllowed.c_str(), currentChar)) {
```

While you're at it, I'd advise against using `strchr` as well, and switch to something like this:

```
std::string SymbolsAllowed = "+-*/%";

if (... && SymbolsAllowed.find(currentChar) == std::string::npos)
```

While you're at it, you should probably forget that you ever even *heard* of the `exit` function. You should never use it in C++. In the case here (exiting from `main`) you should just `return`. Otherwise, throw an exception (and if you want to exit the program, catch the exception in `main` and return from there).

If I were writing this, I'd do the job somewhat differently in general though. `std::string` already has a function to do most of what your loop is trying to accomplish, so I'd set up `symbolsAllowed` to include *all* the symbols you want to allow, then just do a search for anything it doesn't contain:

```
// Add all the authorized characters to the string:
for (unsigned char a = 0; a < std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max(); a++)
    if (isalnum(a) || isspace(a)) // you probably want to allow spaces?
        symbolsAllowed += a;

// ...

auto pos = accentedString.find_first_not_of(symbolsAllowed);
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "Character not allowed: " << accentedString[pos];
    return 1;
}
```