# Code does not output Thai symbols, but Chinese works

Tags: c++, character-encoding, thai

When testing my test c++ code, the English and Chinese characters are displayed  correctly, but the Thai characters lead to `???`. I am using Visual Studio as IDE.

This is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    cout << "ยบางนา-ตราด 25 แขวงบางนาเหนือ 10260 บางนา กรุงเทพฯ 我爱北京天安门" << endl;
}
```

Here is the result

```
Hello World!
??????-???? 25 ?????????????? 10260 ????? ???????? 我爱北京天安门
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849010/output-unicode-to-console-using-c-in-windows

Comment: Use 
 L “ ...” for this with wcout.

Comment: when i use  wcout << L"ยบางนา-ตราด 25 แขวงบางนาเหนือ 10260 บางนา กรุงเทพฯ 我爱北京天安门  de: ĐĄßĞĝ" << endl;  There is nothing display in console

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your question for you. Please refer to [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) next time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

https://blog.csdn.net/longyanbuhui/article/details/104019268

this method solve my question.